# ApexCharts: set display boolean of one specific y axis tooltip

Tags: apexcharts

I am working with a Multi Axis line chart by ApexCharts.js.

### What I want to do

I have multiple y axes and some series share the same y axis. Since there is no y axis ID, you have to create a y axis for every series matching the index of the series. That's why the last y axis is not shown - but its tooltip is still shown (as seen in the following picture).
I want to hide the tooltip for that y axis since the y axis itself is also hidden.

[image: chart y axis tooltip]

I tried to set the tooltip.enabled property for each y axis but that didn't seem to work for individual y axes:

```
yaxis: [{
seriesName: 'TEAM A',
showAlways: true,
title: {
  text: 'A-Axis'
},
tooltip: {
  enabled: true
}}]
```

https://codepen.io/niklhs/pen/OJyyzoa

---

Then I tried to set the tooltip.enabledOnSeries property:

https://codepen.io/niklhs/pen/yLYBeJb

That didn't work either unfortunately.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone running into the same issue:
This is now possible with ApexCharts 3.19.0.
Just update the ApexCharts dependency and you‘re good to go with the following solution:

```
tooltip: {
  enabled: false
}
```

Full code example:
https://codepen.io/niklhs/pen/PoPWvWz